# Impala: list all tables and their created dates in a database

Tags: database, impala

In Impala, is it possible to list all tables in a given database with the date each table is created? Something like:

In `my_database`:

```
TABLE     CREATED_DATE
-----------------------
table_1   2016-01-01
table_2   2016-02-12
table_3   2016-05-03
```

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

I don't Think there is a specific command to do what you are asking for:

What we usually do is to list all tables in a given DB:

```
show tables in db_name
```

then for each table we run:

```
show create table table_name
```

look for the propery  transient_lastDdlTime'='1479222568' which shows the timestamp of the creation time.  you'll have to change that to a "readable date".

You can do this easily on a python script, installing pyodbc package and cloudera Impala ODBC driver.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually trivially easy with one huge but.   With direct READONLY access to the Hive metastore - which may cause additional load that could affect impala and hive performance - you can query table properties directly.

The metastore may be built on a number of different databases - mysql and postgres are both options I believe.  Here is an example from my postgres based Metastore.

```
select "TBL_NAME", "CREATE_TIME" from "TBLS" limit 10;
```